# TCP sockets in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to connect to a ZKteco device using TCP sockets in php. There are a lot of libraries that uses php socket to connect to Zkteco devices but they are using UDP protocol. I want to connect using TCP protocol. There is [this](https://github.com/adrobinoga/pyzatt) library that uses TCP protocol but it is in Python. I want to covert it into Php.

Now I am struggling in creating packets that will be sent to the Zkteco device.

```
self.soc_zk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.soc_zk.connect((ip_addr, dev_port))

# send connect command
#CMD_CONNECT = 0x03e8

self.send_command(CMD_CONNECT)

def send_command(self, cmd, data=None):
    self.soc_zk.send(self.create_packet(cmd, data))

def create_packet(self, cmd_code, data=None, session_id=None,reply_number=None):

    zk_packet = bytearray(START_TAG)  # fixed tag
    zk_packet.extend([0x00] * 2)  # size of payload
    zk_packet.extend([0x00] * 2)  # fixed zeros
    zk_packet.extend(struct.pack('<H', cmd_code))  # cmd code / reply id
    zk_packet.extend([0x00] * 2)  # checksum field

    # append session id
    if session_id is None:
        zk_packet.extend(struct.pack('<H', self.session_id))
    else:
        zk_packet.extend(struct.pack('<H', session_id))

    # append reply number
    if reply_number is None:
        zk_packet.extend(struct.pack('<H', self.reply_number))
    else:
        zk_packet.extend(struct.pack('<H', reply_number))

    # append additional data
    if data:
        zk_packet.extend(data)

    # write size field
    zk_packet[4:6] = struct.pack('<H', len(zk_packet) - 8)
    # write checksum
    zk_packet[10:12] = struct.pack('<H', checksum16(zk_packet[8:]))

    return zk_packet
```

Comment: In PHP a string **is** a byte array. It's entirely unclear from your question what part you're struggling with specifically.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but you probably want something to do with [`pack()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).

Comment: hi , I just want to translate the python code into php.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get data and show it in PHP generated pages u will need it is better to use this [library](https://github.com/fananimi/pyzk). But if u want to use full PHP [TADPHP](https://github.com/cobisja/tad-php) is a better option for u. However, if your task is only to track attendance I recommend you to write ur own server socket for example

```
 /**
 * request to C3 mechanism
 */
public static function check_C3()
{
    $host = IP OF UR DEVICE;
    $port = 4370; // default port
    $array = [];
    $door_id = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) { // parody for setInterval to get all data in real time
        try {
            $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
            $message = hex2bin("special hex which I explained under code");
            socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message));
            socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 3, 'usec' => 0));
            socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 3, 'usec' => 0));
            $result = socket_read($socket, 1024);
            socket_close($socket);
            array_push($array, bin2hex($result));
            $socket = null;
            $result = null;
            $message = null;
            $data = null;
            sleep(1);
        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            continue;
        }
    }
    self::pretty_maker($array, $door_id); // send to DB (Mongo DB recomended)
}
```

To get hex u should install [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and Start attendance in ZKTECO program and listen to ur Mechanism's IP after ur handshake looks to parameter data in Wireshark and save the hex which sent to receive the attendance Hex and decode it. Its a bit harder to realize but it will work much faster. I hope it helps :)